# Why did Melisandre do this in GOT S08E03?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In *The Long Night*, at the end, we see Melisandre

> walk out of Winterfell into the snow-covered landscape and commit suicide. She removes the collar imbued with the magic of the Lord of Light that kept her young, thus the years catch up to her and she quickly falls down on the snow, reduced to an incomplete skeleton it would seem.

It makes little sense to me that she would do that after managing to survive through the whole battle. She did told Seaworth that she was going to die, when she arrived at Winterfell, did she mean it that way? Was this planned all along despite their low probability of survival?

Comment: She was just _really_ committed to her own prophecy?

Answer (score 17):

**She fulfilled her purpose.**

> She helped defeat the white walkers.

That was why Lord of Light kept her alive.

It is the same as with Beric.

As she explained earlier in the episode:

> BERIC: Run! We've gotta go! [] [PANTING] [SPEAKS INDISTINCTLY]
>
> MELISANDRE: The Lord brought him back for a purpose. Now that purpose
>   has been served.

Answer (score 7):

It seemed to me as in her case of, and I mean old, age had finally caught up with her. She was just so old that she died when taking her necklace off. Remember that earlier on in the series we’ve seen her take the necklace off and be fine so it makes sense there’s something more at play here.

The other theory I can think of is that she’d served her purpose, just as Beric had done previously, and so had no need to carry on.

Comment: As I remember, we see her take the necklace off twice. Once at Castle Black, where she appears as a frail old woman, and another time somewhere else, forgot where, and she looks like her normal self. I do like the theory that she served her purpose though.

Comment: +1 Plus, in my opinion, I don't think she really wanted to live anymore. She made terrible mistakes, and even though she contributed to victory later, I don't think she would ever be able to wash away her mistakes in her own mind. Remember how she was right before resurrecting Jon.

Comment: @Sava I am fairly sure the other time is in Dragonstone when she seduces Gendry, but once he's bound she puts it back on again fairly quickly.